# How to convert a polynomial into a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

I have a list of polynomials. Each polynomial looks like:

```
p[1, 2, 5] p[3, 6, 9] p[4, 7, 8] - 3 p[1, 2, 4] p[3, 6, 9] p[5, 7, 8]
```

How to convert each of these polynomials into a list. For example, I would like the above become:

```
{{1, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 8}}, {-3, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {5, 7, 8}}}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Lists must use list brackets. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Comment: `Apply[List, expr, {0, 2}]`

Comment: ...or even `Apply[List, X, {0, ∞}]` to be more general

Comment: @I.M. This doesn't give the coefficient `1` for the first term though

Comment: @MelaGo, right, perhaps having 1 might be redundant like mult by 1, up to OP thou

Answer (score 3):

```
pol = p[1, 2, 5]  p[3, 6, 9]  p[4, 7, 8] - 3  p[1, 2, 4]  p[3, 6, 9]  p[5, 7, 8];
```

---

Using `FactorList` and the following rules:

```
FactorList[#][[All, 1]] & /@ (pol /. Plus[a_, b_] :> {a, b}) /. p[a___] :> {a}
```

> {{1, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 8}}, {-3, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {5, 7, 8}}}

Answer (score 3):

A variant of E. Chan-López answer

```
pol = p[1, 2, 5] p[3, 6, 9] p[4, 7, 8] - 3 p[1, 2, 4] p[3, 6, 9] p[5, 7, 8];
```

```
ReplaceAll[p :> List] @ Query[All, All, 1][FactorList /@ List @@ pol]
```

> {{1, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 8}}, {-3, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {5,
> 7, 8}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
pol = p[1, 2, 5] p[3, 6, 9] p[4, 7, 8] - 3 p[1, 2, 4] p[3, 6, 9] p[5, 7, 8];

If[AtomQ[#[[1]]], List @@@ #, Join[{1}, List @@@ #]] & /@ 
 List @@@ List @@ pol
```

> {{1, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 8}}, {-3, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {5, 7, 8}}}